# Этимология термина "дополнение"

Tags: этимология, грамматика, терминология

Какова история грамматического термина "дополнение"? Что оно, собственно, дополняет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это чисто русский термин. В английском, например, аналог называется просто объектом (object). 
Думаю, что это прямой перевод латинского Completment - дополнение.

Если не в даваться в детали, сейчас под комплементом в лингвистике понимают всякий "сестринский" член рассматриваемого члена.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82_(%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)
Это лишь отдаленно соответствует термину "дополнение" (хотя *дополнение обычно является комплементом глагола*), что вызывает путаницу и мысли о неудачной кальке.

Однако до возникновения структурной лингвистики латинский термин "комплемент" был весьма близок по значению к понятию "дополнение" в русском языке, что, видимо, и стало причиной такого "перевода" названия. 
В любом случае вполне корректно считать, что *дополнение **дополняет** глагол, заполняя необходимые валентности*.

От обстоятельства его отличает то, что дополнение устанавливает необходимые значения действия, а не просто его качественные признаки, то есть это *"дополнение" до полной, цельной смысловой структуры*.

Аналогично и определение не вносит в структуру предложения дополнительной цельности.

Если ограничиться только прямыми дополнениями, то с этим все предельно ясно. В терминах общей лингвистики в любом языке (кроме, возможно, совсем уж экзотических архаичных) выделяются два главных члена и объект (или пациенс) - **прямое дополнение, "дополняющее"** предложение до основной семантически законченной структуры: "Петя любит Машу" - без дополнения фраза была бы  лишена смысла, хотя грамматически она допустима.